# Merging two UIImage's

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage, core-graphics

I want to merge two UIImage's but I'm having some difficulties. I'm playing around with a drawing app where the user when she or he is done will merge their final drawing with their original image they wanted to draw on.

topImage and bottomImage are both final images and need to be merged with their corresponding aspectFit aka ratio.

Then the user can at the end combine both images into one but the thing is that bottomImageView's UIImage will vary in size.

I've been trying to merge them without effecting the newImage or the Aspect ratio (fit)

***Set up:***

I have two UIImageView which are set to (width: 310, height: 400)

**bottomImageView**

bottomImage is JPEG: size ( 600, 800) //other images will vary in ratio

**topImageView**

topImage is PNG (for transparency): size (310, 400)

The bottomImage which is the part of that facebook post is the what the user will theoretically "draw". The topImage (red lines/circle) is the what should be merged with the bottom image.

[image]

How can I merge them together without changing the size of the UIImage's?

I've tried two different ways but to no avail.

way 1:

```
let size = CGSize(width: 300, height: 400)
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size)
let areaSize = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height)
bottomImage.drawInRect(areaSize)
topImage.drawInRect(areaSize, blendMode: CGBlendMode.Normal, alpha: 1.0)
let newImage: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

Way 1, doesn't work because, it creates a new canvas (300, 400) which ultimately alters the size which distorts both my bottomImage and topImage.

Way 2:

```
let bottomImageView: UIImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 310, height: 400))
let topImageView: UIImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 310, height: 400))

bottomImageView.image = topImage
topImageView.image = bottomImage

bottomImageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
topImageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(bottomImageView.frame.size)

bottomImageView.image?.drawInRect(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: bottomImageView.frame.size.width, height: bottomImageView.frame.size.height), blendMode: CGBlendMode.Normal, alpha: 1.0)
topImageView.image?.drawInRect(CGRect(x:0, y: 0, width: topImageView.frame.size.width, height: topImageView.frame.size.height), blendMode: CGBlendMode.Normal, alpha: 1.0)

let newImage: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
```

Way 2: I thought that by putting two UIImageViews then "pressing" them together would work but it ended up distorting my newImage like way 1.

Is it possible to combine them without effecting making the newImage look distorted?

Comment: Maybe you could provide some screen shots.

Comment: I added a screen shot of the images